# iterate json data in react

Tags: javascript, node.js

i am new to react and JSON, i need to `process(iterate)` some JSON data in react the JSON prototype is given below,"i want console each of the room number which belongings to different category", how can a achieve this using map function

please help me out solve the problem. "sorry for my bad English, English is not my first language.

```
let data = {
  "category": {
    "king": [{
        "id": 1,
        "room_no": 101,
        "price": 2000
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "room_no": 102,
        "price": 3000
      }
    ],
    "queen": [{
        "id": 1,
        "room_no": 101,
        "price": 2000
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "room_no": 102,
        "price": 3000
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to iterate over an object like you would do over an array but you don't know how to do it.

Look into javascript's Object.keys(), Object.values() or Object.entries().

- Object.keys(obj) will return an array of keys that can be mapped.

For instance `Object.keys({ foo: 1, bar: 2 })` <=> `['foo', 'bar']`

https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Object/keys

- Object.values does the opposite:

`Object.values({ foo: 1, bar: 2 })` <=> `[1, 2]`

https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Object/values

- And Object.entries() does both.

`Object.entries({ foo: 1, bar: 2 })` <=> `[['foo', 1],['bar', 2]]`

https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Object/entries

So for you a way to map your object is to do:

```
Object.keys(data.category).map(function(categoryName) {
    var category = data.category[categoryName];
    category.map(function(bed) {
        console.log(
            'Category: , ', categoryName,
            ' / Bed: ', bed.id,
            ' / Room number: ', bed.room_no
        );
    });
});
```

[Working fiddle here (remember to open the console to see the result)](https://jsfiddle.net/deb2sghw/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot actually do this using map alone. Or at least, it would be counter to how `map` is usually used.

You can use multiple `map` steps to convert the object to a **nested list**—in this case a list of list of lists of objects—; but you will also need to **flatten** the result of the `map` to a list of numbers. See here:

```js
let data = {
    "category": {
        "king": [{
                "id": 1,
                "room_no": 101,
                "price": 2000
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "room_no": 102,
                "price": 3000
            }
        ],
        "queen": [{
                "id": 1,
                "room_no": 101,
                "price": 2000
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "room_no": 102,
                "price": 3000
            }
        ]
    }
};

const room_nos = Object.values(data)
.map(entry => 
  Object.values(entry)
  .map(category => 
    category.map(room => room.room_no)))
.reduce((result, array) => result.concat(array), [])
.reduce((result, array) => result.concat(array), []);

console.log(room_nos);
```

First, there's three nested `map` steps. The first two use `Object.values` to convert the objects to lists of their values (one for `data` and one for `category`). This gives you a list of list of lists of room descriptors (i.e. objects with `id`, `room_no` and `price` properties). In the third `map` step the room descriptors are projected on the `room_no` properties to obtain a list of list of lists of numbers.

Secondly, we **flatten** the list of list of lists of numbers to a list of numbers using two `reduce` steps.

**OUTPUT:**

```
[
  101,
  102,
  101,
  102
]
```

---

**UPDATE:** you can convert the inner list to a list of elements with type `{ [category: string]: number }` as follows:

```js
    let data = {
        "category": {
            "king": [{
                    "id": 1,
                    "room_no": 101,
                    "price": 2000
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "room_no": 102,
                    "price": 3000
                }
            ],
            "queen": [{
                    "id": 1,
                    "room_no": 101,
                    "price": 2000
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "room_no": 102,
                    "price": 3000
                }
            ]
        }
    };

    const room_nos = Object.values(data)
    .map(entry => 
      Object.entries(entry)
      .map(([category, rooms]) => 
        rooms.map(room => ({ [category]: room.room_no }))))
    .reduce((result, array) => result.concat(array), [])
    .reduce((result, array) => result.concat(array), []);

    console.log(room_nos);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
[
  {
    "king": 101
  },
  {
    "king": 102
  },
  {
    "queen": 101
  },
  {
    "queen": 102
  }
]
```

Comment: if i want to display this in the format like this:   king:101,king:102,queen:101,queen:102

Answer (score 0):

For consoling *room_no*:

```
[].concat.apply([], Object.values(data["category"])).map(i => console.log(i.room_no))
```

Output:

```
101
102
101
102
```

`Object.values(data["category"])` gives the values of king and queen categories in a nested array format and `[].concat.apply([], [nested_array])` flattens it to a single level array in which `Array.prototype.map()` is applied

For formatting the result like *category : room_no*:

```
for(key in data["category"]){
  data["category"][key].map(i => console.log(`${key} : ${i.room_no}`))
}
```

Output:

```
king : 101
king : 102
queen : 101
queen : 102
```

Here looped over `data["category"]` and applied `Array.prototype.map()`.